# Should I remind recruiters about my job application status?

Tags: resume, email

I uploaded my resume through a job recruitment website (for an review/writing position online).  A few days later, someone contacted me asking my Skype details, so he could have a chat with me and see if I'm the right guy for the job.

I replied immediately to that email but till now I haven't heard from him. Is it advisable to 'remind' him or do I assume that I'm not the right guy for the job?

Comment: It's been four days

Comment: You don't have to explicitly chase: you could e.g. reply to ask a question about the role you're applying for, or tell him you wouldn't be available to talk on X day. IMO that'd be OK to do at most once at any time.

Comment: Hmm, alright, I'll wait a day or two more before I send one more in. Thanks for the replies, guys!

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Remind them. Politely of course.  Recruiters are usually working on several positions at the same time....and it gets crazy.  It could be they didn't receive ( or their system misplaced ) your reply.  Good luck

Answer (score 1):

In general, I would wait at least a few days before replying to remind someone, probably a week or so before following up just to remind him--if it's a holiday week(end), perhaps even a few extra days more.

However, if there was no clear communication already about when you should expect to hear from him, since he did not contact you the same day or following day, it would not be out of place to send a brief follow-up email asking if he could let you know (set an appointment) when he is planning to call so you can make sure you will be available and that he will have your undivided attention.

Answer (score 0):

The general rule of thumb is to wait at least a week before sending a reminder message-- but in my experience recruiting, things do occasionally fall through the cracks. I have never minded a candidate requesting an update on status, and your story makes it sound as though your information fell through the cracks with regard to scheduling. A heads-up may be just what this recruiter needs to get you set up for the interview.